# undefined index for PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, calendar

hello people i am doing a function with calendar using AJAX and PHP

```
$showmonth = $_POST['showmonth'];
$showyear = $_POST['showyear'];
$pre_days = date ('w', mktime(0,0,0, $showmonth, 1, $showyear));
$post_days = (6 - (date('w', mktime(0, 0, 0, $showmonth, $day_count, $showyear))));
```

I keep getting error messages saying:

> Notice: Undefined index: showmonth in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar_start.php on line 2
>
> Notice: Undefined index: showyear in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar_start.php on line 3
>
> Warning: cal_days_in_month() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar_start.php on line 8
>
> Warning: mktime() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar_start.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mktime() expects parameter 4 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\calendar_start.php on line 10

I think it has something to do with my AJAX java script but i just dont know what there more parts to the AJAX code but i think this is the part troubling me

```
function next_month() {
    var nextmonth = showmonth + 1;
    if(nextmonth >12) {
        nextmonth = 1;
        showyear = showyear + 1;
        }
showmonth = nextmonth;
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST",url,true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHML = return_data;
        }
}
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
</script>
```

this maybe the problem too:

```
function initialCalendar() {
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
showmonth = month;
showyear = year;
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHML = return_data;
        }
}
    hr.send(vars);
    document.getElementById("showCalendar").innerHTML = "processing...";
}
```

Comment: var_export($_POST); to see what is actually being sent through to post

Comment: You can also try using the browser's web inspector (Chrome, Firebug..) to look at the header of the request and see if you are even posting the data correctly

Comment: Where do you define/set showmonth and showyear? This may be a scoping issue and they may be being sent as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 2):

After spending 5 hours of my life, I found this:
http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Here you can figure out that all you need is just 2 lines:

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", vars.length);
hr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change this in your javascript???

```
var url = "calendar_start.php";
var vars = "showmonth="+showmonth+"&showyear="+showyear;
var final_url = url+"?"+vars;
alert(final_url); //this line should a message with the url, post it please.
hr.open("GET",final,true);
```

That should works.

PS: You pass your url with get params so in you php file you should receive them like

```
$showmonth = $_GET['showmonth']; //I change POST by GET
$showyear = $_GET['showyear']; //DONT forget to chenge this in your php file
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: hello there thanks for the input i put the piece of code in but still received errors...

Comment: put an alert(final_url).....just to make shure the url is well and the values too

Comment: sorry Robert pretty new to all of this can you show me please sorry

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending and receiving parameters using same method(POST/GET)...?
if not so..it may give undefined index error...
i.e. if your sending parameters using GET and receiving parameters using POST or vice versa..